# Closer tie-in between models/stores and React state

Tags: backbone.js, reactjs

I am a bit bemused by this, I am pairing React and Backbone

I have this code

```
getInitialState: function () {
    return localModel.toJSON();
},

componentDidMount: function () {

    this.listenTo(localModel, 'change', this.onLocalModelChange);
    this.listenTo(MappingCollection, 'add remove', this.onMappingCollectionChange);
},

onLocalModelChange: function () {
    this.setState(localModel.toJSON());
},

onMappingCollectionChange: function () {
    this.forceUpdate();
},
```

localModel is a Backbone model, and basically the state for this model is essentially equivalent to the state of the React view. Using the code above, is the best way achieve this relationship? It seems weird that my view state needs to be separate from the Backbone model state at all. What if I want them to be one and the same?

As you can see, I am basically always setting the value for state to the Backbone model.

Answer (score 0):

> localModel is a Backbone model, and basically the state for this model is essentially equivalent to the state of the React view.

That's correct. I would suggest you to do it a bit differently, though. Just put your model as component member, and use it instead of the state.

```
/* delete this:
    getInitialState: function () {
    return localModel.toJSON();
},*/
componentWillMount : function(){
    this.model = localModel;
}    

componentDidMount: function () {
    this.listenTo( this.model, 'change', this.refresh );
    this.listenTo( MappingCollection, 'add remove', this.refresh );
},

refresh : function () {
    this.forceUpdate();
}
```

Or you can just use our integration layer instead. It make things way simpler. https://github.com/Volicon/NestedReact